# Why doesn't the lack of pointwise convergence of $f_n(x)=x^n$ contradict the fact that $C[0,1]$ is Banach?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

On [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4050373/878105), the function $f_n(x)=x^n$ in the interval $[0,1]$ is given as a pathologic example with pointwise convergence.

Can I say that this Cauchy sequence does not (pointwise) converge because the limit of the sequence is a function like this (not continuous):

[image]

without specifying any particular norm? I read that pointwise convergence, doesn't imply $d_\infty$ (uniform) convergence, and that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. But does lack of pointwise convergence negate uniform convergence?

Does this contradict in any way (or under certain norms) the fact that $C[a,b]$ with respect to $\Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$ is a Banach space? In other words, why is not an example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge to some $f\in C[0,1]$?

Comment: "Can I say that this Cauchy sequence is not complete" No, because sequences aren't called complete. You can say that the space under consideration is not complete. "If so, under which norm is this space not a Banach space?" You could try with other $L^p$-norms.

Comment: @amsmath Can you explain this a bit further with an example of another $L^p$ norm that illustrates the concept of Banach space?

Comment: You can begin by realizing that when you say that the limit of the sequence that function, you are being imprecise. The sequence converges **pointwise** to that function, but with other norms the limit of the sequence is the function $0$ and with other norms the limit doesn't exists.

Comment: Also, the graph of the pointwise limit doesn't looks like a mirror "L". It looks like a segment and a point.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate You should try yourself. For example, you could find out whether that very sequence converges in $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you for pointing out this blatant oversight about the L. This function, then, is not in the continuous functions space, but I don't get the limit issue you point out.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate The issue is that you said "the limit of the sequence". What do you mean by "limit"? The "pointwise limit"? The limit with an $L^p$ norm? The limit with convergence in measure? The space functions usually have a lot of distinct types of convergence, so you need to pay attention to which notion of convergence you want. Depending on that, your sequence of functions will converge to the limit you gave, to the function $0$ or not converge at all.

Comment: @Numericallyilliterate Are you aware that $C([0,1])$ with the supremum norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ (uniform convergence) is not the same that $L^\infty([0,1])$ ?

Comment: Lack of pointwise convergence does negate uniform convergence, by simple contraposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of a sequence being "Cauchy" is inherently a metric concept. When you talk about a Cauchy sequence, you need to be talking about convergence in a metric. Pointwise convergence does not correspond to any metric (this can be proven). If you use the $\|f\|_{\infty}$ metric, the sequence isn't Cauchy. For any finite $m$, there is some point $x_m$ sufficiently close to $1$ for which $x_{m}^{m} \approx 1$. However, if you take $n$ sufficiently large, $x_{m}^{n} \approx 0$, so that $\|x^{n} - x^{m}\|_{\infty} \approx 1$. Since the sequence isn't Cauchy, it won't converge in our metric.

As for the question: if the pointwise limit is not continuous, can the sequence converge in the $\|f\|_{\infty}$ metric? The answer here is no: if it did converge in $\|f\|_{\infty}$, the limit would be continuous (because our space is Banach, so complete) , and since the pointwise limit has to be the same as the uniform limit, we would arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Can I infer from your answer that I would not be able to find "pathologic" non-convergent Cauchy sequences of continuous functions in this interval using $\Vert f \Vert_\infty$? And that is why this is a Banach space?

Comment: Or, in other words, could we find a "pathologic" non-convergent Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ in some other metric?

Comment: If the sequence is Cauchy, it must converge. That's what it means for a space to be complete.

Answer (score 1):

After some [research on the topic](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch9.pdf), I think that the answer is no (as canonically answered by Elchanan), and the critical bit is his sentence, "*Pointwise convergence does not correspond to any metric (this can be proven)*."

But there remains the meta-questions of what is happening with that "pathologic" function, and what words would give the uninitiated some sense of direction.

The problem with the sequence $\{x^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in the interval $[0,1]$ is that it is **pointwise convergent**, but **not uniformly convergent**.

The sequence $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$ if $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $x \in [0,1].$ There is no $\varepsilon!$

The limit of a pointwise convergent sequence of continuous functions does not have to be continuous, and does not generally preserve boundedness. In this case:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x) = 
    \begin{cases} 0 & (0\leq x\lt 1) \\ 1 & (x=1) \end{cases}$$

In uniform convergence, the uniform norm is introduced. Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, but not the other way around.

A sequence of functions converges uniformly if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n≥N$ and **all** $x \in [0,1],$ $d(f_n(x),f(x))<\varepsilon,$ where $d(f, g) =  \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)|.$

The space $C[0,1]$ with the infinity metric is complete (Banach), but the sequence $x^n$ is not Cauchy.

The link to Cauchy sequences is that $$\small \text{uniform convergence}\iff \text{Cauchy under the }\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty \text{ uniform or infinity norm}. $$

The lack of uniform convergence is explained in Elchanan's answer, as well as [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Eangenent/521.2017s/UniformConvergence.html) by contradiction:

> If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly, then the limit function must be $f(x)=0$ for $x∈[0,1)$ and $f(1)=1.$ Uniform convergence implies that for any $ϵ>0$ there is an $Nϵ \mathbb N$ such that $|x^n−f(x)|<ϵ$ for all $n≥ \mathbb N$ and all $x∈[0,1].$ Assuming this is indeed true we may choose $ϵ,$ in particular, we can choose $ϵ=1/2.$ Then there is an $N∈ \mathbb N$ such that for all $n≥N$ we have $|x^n−f(x)|<1/2.$ We may choose $n$ and $x.$ Let us choose $n=N,$ and $x=(\frac 3 4)^{1/N}.$ Then we have $f(x)=0$ and thus
>
> $$|f_N(x)−f(x)|=x^N−0=\frac3 4>\frac 1 2, $$
>
> a contradiction.